# How to add new tab dynamically (onClick of button) using jQuery v2.1.4 in Magento CE 1.9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, tabs, magento-1.9

I want to add new `tab-component` 
The current structure of the tab is

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">

        <!-- Name of the Tab -->
        <dt class="tab"><span id="a-1">Tab #1</span></dt>
        <dt class="tab"><span id="a-2">Tab #2</span></dt>
        <dt class="tab"><span id="a-3">Tab #3</span></dt>
        <dt class="tab"><span id="a-4">Tab #4</span></dt>

        <!-- Content of the Tab -->            
        <dd class="tab-container">
            <div class="tab-content" id="b-1">
                <h1>This is from Tab #1</h1>
            </div>
        </dd>
        <dd class="tab-container">
            <div class="tab-content" id="b-2">
                <h1>This is from Tab #2</h1>
            </div>
        </dd>
        <dd class="tab-container">
            <div class="tab-content" id="b-3">
                <h1>This is from Tab #3</h1>
            </div>
        </dd>
        <dd class="tab-container">
            <div class="tab-content" id="b-4">
                <h1>This is from Tab #4</h1>
            </div>
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```

Magento internally converts the `<dt>` into `<ul><li>` components and create tabs-heading and the same `<dl><dd>` as the tabs-body

The Runtime Structure of the same is

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">

<!-- Name of the Tab -->  
<ul class="toggle-tabs">
    <li class="current"><span id="a-1">Tab #1</span></li>
    <li class=""><span id="a-2">Tab #2</span></li>
    <li class=""><span id="a-3">Tab #3</span></li>
    <li class="last"><span id="a-4">Tab #4</span></li>
</ul>

<!-- Content of the Tab -->    
<dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
    <dd class="tab-container current">
        <div id="a-1" class="tab-content" id="b-1">
            <h1>This is from Tab #1</h1>
        </div>
    </dd>
    <dd class="tab-container current">
        <div id="a-1" class="tab-content" id="b-1">
            <h1>This is from Tab #2</h1>
        </div>
    </dd>
    ... Tab 3
    ... Tab 4 so on.
</dl>
```

Current Output looks like
[image: Current Output of Tabs]

Help !